# Pesquisa utilizando dois parâmetros no JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Boa Noite a todos,
Estou empacado aqui em uma lógica, fiz o DAO para todo o CRUD do meu projeto só que nele não terá só a pesquisa pelo ID e também estou tentando fazer algum método que pesquise o pedido pelo ID e também pela data cadastrada. Só que na hora de fazer a pesquisa ele está dando este retorno:

```js
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.exemplo.model.Pedido. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.sql.Date
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1135)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1068)
 at com.exemplo.repositorio.MySQLPedidoDAO.pesquisarPorData(MySQLPedidoDAO.java:82)
 at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.btBuscarActionPerformed(ViewPedidos.java:322)
 at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.access$000(ViewPedidos.java:23)
 at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos$1.actionPerformed(ViewPedidos.java:106)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.exemplo.model.Pedido. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.sql.Date
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:133)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1066)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2540)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:951)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1110)
 ... 41 more
```

Meus métodos ficaram desta forma:
Classe DAO:

```js
public interface DAO <T, K> {

    public void inserir(T o);
    
    public void alterar(T o);

    public void excluir(T o);

    public T pesquisar(K id);

    public List<T> listar();
    
}
```

PedidoDAO:

```js
public interface PedidoDAO extends DAO <Pedido, Long> {
    
    public Pedido pesquisarPorData(Date dataCadastro);
    
}
```

MySQLPedidoDAO:

```js
public class MySQLPedidoDAO implements PedidoDAO {

    public ConnectionFactory cf = null;

    public MySQLPedidoDAO(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        this.cf = cf;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Pedido pesquisar(Long id) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        Pedido pedido = cf.createEm().find(Pedido.class, id);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        //erro ao deletar pois o factory já está fechado
        //emf.close();
        return pedido;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Pedido pesquisarPorData(Date dataCadastro) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        // ERRO ABAIXO!!!!!
        // ERRO ABAIXO!!!!!
        Pedido pedido = cf.createEm().find(Pedido.class, dataCadastro);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        //erro ao deletar pois o factory já está fechado
        //emf.close();
        return pedido;
    }
    
}
```

ViewPedidos:

```js
public class ViewPedidos extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    private MySQLPedidoDAO mspdao;
    private Pedido ped;
    private boolean editavel;
    
    /* Getters e Setters de editavel e ped  */
    
    private void btPesquisaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        habilitarApenasOSeData();
        limparCampos();
        tfPedido.setEditable(true);
        tfPedido.requestFocus();
        btBuscar.setEnabled(true);
    } 
    
    
    
    private void btBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
        MySQLPedidoDAO mspdao = new MySQLPedidoDAO(cf);
        Pedido ped = new Pedido();
        
        if(tfPedido.getText().length() == 0  &&  tfDataCad.getText().length() == 0){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Não é possível pesquisar, Favor preencher os campos", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
             ped = mspdao.pesquisar(Long.parseLong(tfPedido.getText()));
             ped = mspdao.pesquisarPorData(new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date)tfDataCad.getValue()).getTime()));
             setPed(ped);
             setEditable(true);
             carregarCampos();
             habilitarTextFieldEBotoes();
        }
              
    }   
    
    
}
```

Testei comentando os códigos que envolvem o campo de data e rodou sem problemas pesquisando pelo id, dai nessa parte inventei de tentar fazer uma "gambiarra" para pegar a pesquisa pelo id e a data e veio aquele erro acima no stack trace. Gostaria de saber aonde eu devo mudar? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está utilizando o método find para buscar por data, esse método serve para buscar um objeto pela chave primária,
a exception diz que você está passando um Date onde deveria passar um Long.

Tente mudar o tipo de retorno da interface e substituir a implementação pelo método abaixo.

```
   @Override
    public List<Pedido> pesquisarPorData(Date dataCadastro) {
       String jpql = "select p from Pedido p where dataCadastro = :data";
       List<Pedido> pedidos =  cf.createEm()
                .createQuery(jpql)
                .setParameter("data", dataCadastro)
                .getResultList();

        return pedidos;

    }
```

Comment: Olá Matheus!! Eu nem sabia que o searchEm().find(Class.class, id) era somente para objetos pela chave primária agora já consigo estar mais ciente, este método escrito no caso seria para retornar uma lista de vetores ou dá para retornar um só objeto por vez? Tentei executar agora e alterar a chamada de: ped = mspdao.pesquisarPorData(new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date)tfDataCad.getValue()).getTime‌​())); para: pedidos = (Pedido) mspdao.pesquisarPorData(new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date)tfDataCad.getValue()).getTime‌​())); mas agora ele está retornando ClassCastException

Comment: O que estou em dúvida é de fazer uma pesquisa individual pesquisando por um só id só que com os dois parâmetros como se fosse: "select * from pedido where id = ? and dataCadastro = '?'"; e retornar um objeto do tipo pedido. Dá para fazer pelo createQuery() tudo em um?